# Throughput calculation in jmeter with respect to aggregate report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, throughput

I'm manually validating the **throughput** value what we get in jmeter aggregate report.

Throughput means (number of requests)/(total time duration to hit the server and to get the response).

In other words Throughput=1/(end time of the sampler-starting time of the sampler)

in the attached image as you can see throughput in first row is 0.18097/sec.

If i have to get 0.1809790969143064/sec as thoughput then 1/(0.1809790969143064)=5.5255Sec or 5525.5msec  should be the duration .

Can anyone help me in this.

[image: Aggregate report]

So i want to know how exaclty we are getting throughput value for individual samplers in jmeter.

Please help me with any formula which works for all or how can we calculate throughput manually which gives the same value compared to aggregate report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very good to validate your performance test results.
But in this case your definition of throughput is wrong - good to identify so you can interpret the results correctly.

Probably worth looking up a definition for throughput. JMeter provides its own :

"Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)."

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html